# Error al crear un elemento SCAFFOLDING en .netcore MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, entity-framework

Error al ejecutar el generador de codigos.

Estoy intentando crear el elemento scaffolding mvc con vistas que usan entity framework

Me da el siguiente error. Estuve investigando pero no encontré solución

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No redactes en mayúsculas, pues es considerado hablar a gritos

Comment: debes especificar cual versión de .Net core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para Dot net core 2.1 o posterior..

Debes usar dotnet cli, esto es para hacerlos desde una terminal y luego trabajarlo en el visual Studio (creo que usas 2019) primero instalar el generador de codigo...

```
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
```

Luego el scalfolding de mvc

```
dotnet new mvc -o tuAppmvc
```

Tambien Adicionar un package..

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
```

y hacer un build al proyecto.

```
dotnet build
```

Recuerda hacer esto dentro la carpeta del proyecto que hayas creado!

Para mas información consulta esta [fuente](https://gavilanch.wordpress.com/2018/04/28/asp-net-core-2-haciendo-scaffolding-con-el-dotnet-cli-aspnet-codegenerator/)